# The future of "Almost Human"?

Tags: production, cancellation, almost-human

[**Almost Human** is a sci-fi buddy cop/crime drama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_Human_(TV_series)) revolving a tough as *bones*, old school human cop his deadpan snarker *almost human* synthetic robot partner. Well rated, Fox decided to cancel it after a single season in 2014 ([like so many other scifi shows on it's network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefly_(TV_series))). While many fans petitioned for it to be continued, or shopped around, nothing has come about it. Syfy and Netflix haven't commented on it either.

The show ended without a finale cliffhanger (thankfully), but had it's season-wide plot left wide open. What's behind the wall? What was the roboticist planning? How was inSyndicate involved? Will Kennex and Stahl get together? Minor and Major plot points were unresolved. Since the series is original and not an adaptation of a film or book series, there is nowhere else to find an answer to these questions.

My question then is, **is there any source for information on what would have been shown in a Season 2? Or is the show still being shopped around? Is there plans for a one-off special addressing those plot points?** Any interview would be helpful.

Comment: And then Fox goes and orders Minority Report, already seen to be a crappier version of Almost Human. Damnit Fox!

Comment: Look, this show was cancelled ***almost a year and a half ago***. It was an expensive show which had not great ratings, so there was little chance of other outlets picking it up. It didn't happen then, and it's never going to happen now.

Comment: That's not a ducking close reason @paulie_d

Comment: And series have been revived after decades.

Comment: @Paulie_D That sounds more like an answer than a close-reason (provided you have some backing for that).

Comment: OK. OK...It just seemed to me that no answer was ever going to be possible.